# issue with python Tkinter drop down menu

Tags: python, tkinter, arguments, drop-down-menu

The following code is a program to append buttons onto an existing program so selection can occur on a more friendly interface rather than inside the code. I am trying to use drop down menu's but the setEthAnt1 function seems to have an error: TypeError: setEthAnt1() takes no arguments (1 given). I do not know what arg i am failing to pass in. Does anyone have any ideas?

```
from Tkinter import *
import ThreegroupsGraphics as three

def run():
    three.main()

def setEthAnt1():
    name = var.get()
    print name
    three.OneTo2Ant = name
    print three.OneTo2Ant

root = Tk()
var = StringVar()
var.set("Group 1 Ethnic Antagonism")
OptionMenu(root, var, "1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10", command = setEthAnt1).pack()
butn = Button(root, text = 'run',  command = run)
butn.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 3):

When you specify a command for an `OptionMenu`, the value of the selected item will be sent into the command, which essentially makes your var.get() unneeded. See below:

```
from Tkinter import *
import ThreegroupsGraphics as three

def run():
    three.main()

def setEthAnt1(name):
    print name
    three.OneTo2Ant = name
    print three.OneTo2Ant

root = Tk()
var = StringVar()
var.set("Group 1 Ethnic Antagonism")
OptionMenu(root, var, "1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10", command = setEthAnt1).pack()
butn = Button(root, text = 'run',  command = run)
butn.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

If you don't want `setEthAnt1` to have any parameters and still use `var.get()`, you can make the command for the `OptionMenu` a lamda function like so:

```
OptionMenu(root, var, "1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10", command = lambda _: setEthAnt1).pack()
```